# Excel 2007, How to avoid scatter chart data points overlap

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook and the following sheets
Dashboard, IImpactchart.

Dashboard, which have candidate name, influence reference and impact reference

### Candidate | Impact | Influence

Which have values of

Candidate1, Impact value = 3, Influence value = 2

Candate 2, Impact value = 3, Influence value =2

In the chart, we need to display the corresponding row number in the coordinate of (3,2). Its plotting for only single candidate. If we have more candidate with same value, the data-points are overlapping one above the other. How can we shift the data-points separated by commas ?? or any other way.

Chart attached
[Please click here to see the Chart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aSDU.jpg)

Chart Required
[Please click here to see the required chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAvN4.jpg)

VBA used

```
Dim Counter As Integer, ChartName As String, xVals As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c As ChartObject
Set c = Sheets("IImpactchart").ChartObjects("Chart 1")
c.Activate
xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
xVals = Mid(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, ","), xVals, _
  Mid(Left(xVals, InStr(xVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
xVals = Left(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, "!"), xVals, ",") - 1)

Do While Left(xVals, 1) = ","
  xVals = Mid(xVals, 2)
Loop

For Counter = 1 To Range(xVals).Cells.Count
 If (Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value = 0) Then
     Exit Sub
 End If

 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).HasDataLabel = _
     True
 ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(Counter).DataLabel.Text = Counter + 5

Next Counter
```

(Counter is to increment by 5 to get the correct row number) - its working

Now i need to solve the overlapping.

Help appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to increase .DataLabel.Width? It may help.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion..No i didn't tried, but the following support helped me... appreciate for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your current code works and that the only problem is the overlap, the code below should solve your problem.

This solution involves the use of an array named `LabelArray` that stores the point number of the first point to occupy the spot on the grid. Then, instead of creating a new label for the new points, it simply **adds to the existing label** of that first point.

```
Sub LabelsNoOverlap()

    Dim Counter As Integer, ChartName As String, xVals As String, yVals As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim c As ChartObject
    Set c = Sheets("IImpactchart").ChartObjects("Chart 2")
    c.Activate

    'Find address of the X values
    xVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
    xVals = Mid(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, ","), xVals, _
        Mid(Left(xVals, InStr(xVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
    xVals = Left(xVals, InStr(InStr(xVals, "!"), xVals, ",") - 1)

    'Not sure why this loop from your code is useful, but let's leave it.
    Do While Left(xVals, 1) = ","
        xVals = Mid(xVals, 2)
    Loop

    'Find address of the Y values
    yVals = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
    yVals = Mid(yVals, InStr(InStr(yVals, ","), yVals, _
        Mid(Left(yVals, InStr(yVals, "!") - 1), 9)))
    yVals = Right(yVals, Len(yVals) - InStr(yVals, ","))
    yVals = Left(yVals, InStr(InStr(yVals, "!"), yVals, ",") - 1)

    'Again, not sure why this loop from your code is useful, but let's leave it.
    Do While Left(yVals, 1) = ","
        yVals = Mid(yVals, 2)
    Loop

    Dim DimY As Long, DimX As Long
    DimY = 10
    DimX = 10

    Dim LabelArray() As Long
    ReDim LabelArray(1 To DimX, 1 To DimY)

    Dim src As Series, pts As Points
    Set src = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    Set pts = src.Points

    'Clear labels
    src.HasDataLabels = False

    For Counter = 1 To Range(xVals).Cells.Count
        If (Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value = 0) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim xCoord As Long, yCoord As Long
        xCoord = Range(xVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Value2
        yCoord = Range(yVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Value2

        If LabelArray(xCoord, yCoord) = 0 Then 'No overlap
            LabelArray(xCoord, yCoord) = Counter
            pts(Counter).HasDataLabel = True
            pts(Counter).DataLabel.Text = Counter + 5
        Else 'Overlap
            pts(LabelArray(xCoord, yCoord)).DataLabel.Text = _
                pts(LabelArray(xCoord, yCoord)).DataLabel.Text & "," & Counter + 5
        End If
    Next Counter

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note that the code would work as long as the values for your X and Y values are ranging from 1 to 10. You could also change the upper bound by changing the value of `DimX` and `DimY`.

Additionally, I should mention that this code has limitations:

- In its current version, it cannot handle whole numbers equal or smaller than 0 for the X and Y values.
- The method to parse the SERIES formula is not robust to the presence of certain characters such as a comma in the sheet name (yes, that's allowed for some reason).
- The way the code is specified assumes that the data series are **vertically orientated**. Maybe, for a more general solution, you would have to test for the orientation of the data or you could implement something using `src.XValues` and `src.Values` (for Y values) which returns arrays instead of a range.

Comment: Thank you so much Decimal. It worked...X and Y values always be within 1 and 5. Appreciate your support

Comment: @AjKu I'm glad I could help. If this (or any future answer) solves your question, please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.  This is not an obligation, but it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Okay, did so. Thanks again.

Comment: @DecimanTurn.. im facing an issue now. i have entered 3 rows with different X and Y values,(X= 3 Y=5, X= 4 Y= 3 and X= 2 Y=5) its all plotting correctly.  Entered 4,5,6,7 with same X and Y values (X=3 Y=5) and showing correctly. In the 8th row, entered X= 2 and Y=3, but in the chart, the corresponding point, datalabel is not displaying and its displaying together with previous 2,5 coordinate. Hope my question is clear.. any solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but are you running the macro every time you add a new point?

Comment: Sorry, I will try to make it simple. If we have same x coordinate and y coordinates for 4-5 rows,  whatever the coordinates after that will show just the point, but not the data label.  For the data label to display, I need to run the macro each time, whenever I  add/edit values.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to reproduce the problem you described, so I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks @decimalTurn  No problem

Comment: Solved... issue with yCoord = Range(yVals).Cells(Counter, 1).Value2. changed to yCoord = Range(yVals).Cells(Counter, 2).Value2